# How to add "see more"/ "see less" functionality button at the end incase number of tags exceeds 3 lines

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile-development

There is a list of tags whose number is dynamic. Those tags will be filling up to 3 lines of an area when those tags exceed more than 3 lines. The "See more" button should be visible and when the user clicks on it, it should open the whole list then the "See less" button will appear at the end of the whole list of tags, and on clicking on "see less" it should go back to the previous state. How to achieve this behavior in Flutter.
I tried with wrap but I am not able to achieve see more/see less functionality. I am attaching below a rough diagram of what want.

```
class FlightSeeMoreSeeLessWidgetState extends State<FlightSeeMoreSeeLessWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      AnimatedSize(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: isExpanded
                  ? const BoxConstraints()
                  : const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30),
              child: Wrap(
                key: const Key('Airline'),
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                spacing: kSize16,
                runSpacing: kSize8,
                children: widget.widgetList,
              ))),
      isExpanded
          ? InkWell(
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(
                  'See less',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () => setState(() => isExpanded = false),
            )
          : InkWell(
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text('See more', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
              ),
              onTap: () => setState(() => isExpanded = true))
    ]);
  }
}
```

In the above widgetList is the list of tags. I achieved most of it, need to clear some code and use bloc instead of setState. But now my issue is. When see more button is activated i.e not expanded state. It is overlapping the list of tags. I tried different clip behavior in wrap still not getting desired result.

**Update**
This code works fine, but my issue was with the List-->Widget was an InkWell with Ink decoration, but it wasn't wrapped in Material. Wrapping is with Material solves the issue

[image: Issue Overlapping]

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please review [ask]. We have no idea what you are doing to display the tags, so it is impossible to offer any suggestions.